# Does anyone have a way to modify Ticket to Ride to accommodate six people?

Tags: house-rules, ticket-to-ride

I recently bought Ticket to Ride to play at our monthly game night, which consists of three couples, i.e. six people. Stupid me, didn't read the five player limit before ordering the game. I've played a few times now, and I really like the game, but can't think of any way to accommodate an extra player.

So, am I stuck making someone sit out or putting two people on one team if we want to play this with six people? Or has someone else come up with some modification to make this work with one extra person?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The obvious approach is to simply reduce the number of carriages each player has available, by enough to allow another player to join in. Normally each player has 45 carriages. In the 5 player game that makes 225 carriages available to place on the board. Divide by 6 instead, and you get 37 carriages per person.

So your only issue then is where to get your extra carriages. You can either make substitutions yourself, or buy one of the other versions (e.g. [Ticket to Ride: Nordic Countries](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/31627/ticket-to-ride-nordic-countries), or [Ticket to Ride: Märklin Edition](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/21348/ticket-to-ride-marklin-edition)), which come with other train colours.

I wouldn't expect to see any other significant balance issues with the extra player - Ticket to Ride is a pretty straightforward game.

Comment: +1 Good suggestion for fixing the total number of carriages.  Re. Balance issues: I would expect an extra player will make it harder to complete routes.  Although I doubt this will upset the game-play vastly, it might make the game less 'satisfying'.

Comment: Having fewer carriages also means that you'd be able to complete fewer routes. This may not be so much of an issue on European maps, but on the North America map, you'll only have enough time to complete the initial routes, factoring in the likelihood of that line between Houston and New Orleans (or even between Seattle and Vancouver) being blocked even before you can place your first couple of cars. You can use paper clips for the carriages of the 6th player.

Answer (score 19):

Ticket to Ride Asia has a double-sided board, one side for up to 5 players playing individually, and the other side for 6 players in 3 pairs. It's very well written and playing in pairs doesn't just mean a straightforward teaming up as you only share half your information with your partner. Complicated on first play... but all the best games are!

Comment: What does playing in pairs do?  You and the person across from you each share a pool of trains of one color?

Comment: @NealTibrewala: Each pair plays a single color, but it's more complicated than that. While each partner has their own train cards and tickets, the also share a set that either can use (the expansion comes with card holders for the shared hand). Each time you draw train cards, one of the two cards must go in the shared hand. However, there is a limitation as well: the partners are not allowed to discuss their strategy in any way. Among other things, that means that your partner has no way of knowing what tickets are in your hand, other than by inferring based on the routes you take.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to consider adding stations (or increasing the number of stations if you have Ticket to Ride: Europe) if you find the board gets too crowded and people are blocked completely from their routes too often (Note: too often. It should be allowed to happen sometimes)

> A Train Station allows its owner to
>   use one, and only one, of the routes
>   belonging to another player, into (or
>   out of) that city to help him connect
>   the cities on his Destination Tickets.
>   Stations may be built on any
>   unoccupied city, even if it currently
>   h> as no claimed routes into it. Two
>   players may never build a Station in
>   the same city. Each player may build a
>   maximum of one Station per turn, and
>   three Stations throughout the course
>   of the game. To build his first
>   Station, a player plays and discards
>   one Train card from his hand, and
>   places one of his colored Train
>   Stations on the chosen city.To build a
>   second Station, the player must play
>   and discard a set of two cards of any
>   one color; and to buil   his third, a
>   set of three Train cards of any one
>   color. As usual, you can replace any
>   number of cards by Locomotives. If a
>   player uses the same Station to help
>   connect cities on several different
>   Tickets, he must use the same route
>   into the city with the Station for all
>   of those Tickets. The Train Station
>   owner does not need to decide which
>   route he will use until the end of the
>   game. A player is never required to
>   build any Stations. For each Station a
>   player has not used, four points are
>   added to his score at the end of the
>   game.

> Remember that each Station played
>   allows its owner to use one (and only
>   one) route belonging to another player
>   into that City for the purpose of
>   completing a Destination Ticket. If a
>   player uses the same Station to help
>   connect cities on the paths of several
>   different Destination Tickets, he must
>   use the same route into or out of the
>   city with the Station for all Tickets.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, we tried a method that worked for us (family of 6). Using the original US map we divided up into three teams. Each player was given two cards and could only keep one. There was no "sharing" of information just trains. We each were given 4 train cards to start the game and we were off. New tickets could only be drawn when you finished your original route. Two tickets were drawn and only one could be taken. It made for a very quick and frantic game but was enjoyed by everyone. Since we are all familiar with the routes we could guess our team members goal and help connect our trains quicker. We have played this way a few times and so far no major snags (except when someone gets the track you wanted before you). It was actually a very simple and nice solution to our six player problem.

Answer (score 1):

Play the Ticket to Ride Map Collection: Volume 1 – Team Asia & Legendary Asia.

Play the Team Asia in the form of 3 teams of 2 persons. Playing in form of teams it is far more tense.

Answer (score 1):

I have played TTR Europe with six players several times using an extra set of train pieces from TTR Nordic. We had 45 pieces each and using 3 stations it worked just as well as five players

Answer (score 1):

The ticket to ride Old West map (part of the France edition originally released in 2016) has a sixth colour so that it can be played by six players. From [TTR Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_to_Ride_(board_game))

[image: Wiki screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

We played with scrabble letters for trains(on the US version). Played it twice no problem. Loads of competition :)

Comment: It sure seems like an answer to me.

Comment: Welcome to B&CG Nile.  It would be great if you could expand on this answer a bit.  Did you change the number of trains available to each person?